# Why my program erases parts of a table while printing it?

Tags: c

$ At school we have to do a project in C, and i'm very new in C (about 3 months of programming). I would lije to have a little help with this problem that drives me crazy.

The project is a game, and in this game, you have to kill the ships that are on the water. In the program, at first you will see that i ask for what to do (a menu ), if I press 1, the program will start doing a new game. First you have to choose how you want to play, 1vs1... etc, but only we have to do a computer vs computer(case 3 of the second switch) . Later you have to give the dimension of the chart where there will be the ships. The dim has to be between 8 and 10. 
There you will see 3 functions : $

```
void taulellprincipalinterrogants(char taulell_vaixells_interrogants[][DIM_MAX], int dim);
```

That creates the chart with '?' on it with the dim you gave earlier.

```
void taulellprincipalinterrogants ( char taulell_vaixells_interrogants[][DIM_MAX] , int dim)
{



int i, j;

printf("\n");
printf("  ");
for (i=0; i<dim; i++)
{
    printf(" %i", i+1);
}
printf("  ");
printf("\n");
for (i=0; i<dim; i++)
{
    printf("\n%c ", i+65);

    for (j=0; j<dim; j++)
    {
        taulell_vaixells_interrogants[i][j] = '?' ;
        printf(" %c", taulell_vaixells_interrogants[i][j]);
    }
}

printf("\n");


printf("\n");


}


inicia_taulell (dim, taulell_vaixells);
```

this one was done by the teacher, and puts ships on it randomly. We don't have the code, it's a .o and i can't open it.

```
void imprimeix_taulell (char taulell_vaixells[][DIM_MAX], int dim );
```

And this function, prints it.

```
void imprimeix_taulell( char taulell_vaixells[][DIM_MAX], int dim)
{


int i, j;

printf("\n");
printf("  ");
printf("Impresion del tablero con barcos aleatoriamente colocados \n");

printf("\n");
printf("  ");
for (i=0; i<dim; i++)

{
    printf(" %i", i+1);
}

printf("\n");

for (i=0; i<dim; i++)
{
    printf("\n%c ", i+65);

    for (j=0; j<dim; j++)
    {

        printf(" %c", taulell_vaixells[i][j]);
    }
}

printf("\n");
printf("\n");

printf("\n");


}
```

This is all ok. But later, when I have to go to the second menu, and to play, while i'm trying to make a shot with the ''Dispara'' function (also was given by the teacher ) , the chart it isn't complete.... It prints something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 

A - - - - - - X

B - -     -   

C     - - - - 

D X X X X - - -

E - - - - 

F - - X X - - -

G - -     - -

H X X X X     X
```

I can't do a good table, but there should be 8 ''things'' on each line...there are some missing things.

There are missing parts.... i can't understand why does this...and if i don't have the entire chart, i can't make the shots and finish the game...
what should i do? HELP! PLEASE! .

This is the entire main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "tipus.h"
#include "funcions.h"
#include "vaixells.h"






int main ()
{



int col=0, tecla = 0,tecla2=0, opciocrearjoc,dim,res,cont;
char fila,taulell_vaixells[dim][DIM_MAX],     taulell_vaixells_interrogants[dim][DIM_MAX];
bool nofimenu, noficrearjoc,segonmenu,vaixellstrobats=false;


/* Codi de l'algorisme */

nofimenu=true;
noficrearjoc=true;
segonmenu=true;
while ( (nofimenu) && (tecla!=4 ) && (tecla!=6)) {


      /* Menu principal sense algunes opcions */


    printf ("********************   HUNDIR LA FLOTA   ********************\n");

    printf("1.Crear un nou joc\n");
    printf("2.Carregar un joc emmagatzemat\n");
    printf("5.Veure pòdium\n");
    printf("6.Sortir del joc\n");

    printf(" ************************ \n");

    printf("Escull una opció : \n");

    printf("\n");



    scanf("%d",&tecla);


      /* Opcio per a poder entrar en el crear joc nou i poder escollir mode de joc */

    switch (tecla) {
        case 1:
            system("clear");
            printf("Has triat la opcio de crear un nou joc\n");
             while (noficrearjoc==true) {


            printf("Per crear un nou joc, has d'escollir el mode de joc:\n \t 1 - Un jugador \n  \t 2 - Dos jugadors \n \t 3 - L'ordinador sol \n");

                 scanf("%d",&opciocrearjoc);

                 switch (opciocrearjoc){
                     case 1 :
                         printf( "Has triat la opcio d'un jugador\n");
                         printf(" He escollit el primer nivell, per sortir apreta el 6 : \n") ;
                         scanf("%d",&tecla);
                         break;


                     case 2 :
                          printf( "Has triat la opcio de dos jugadors\n");
                         printf(" He escollit el primer nivell, per sortir apreta el 6 : \n") ;
                         scanf("%d",&tecla);
                         break;

                     case 3:
                           /* Nivell escollit = Nivell 1 */
                         system("clear");
                          printf( "Has triat la opcio de l'ordinador sol\n");

                         printf( " Introdueix la dimensió del taulell, que pot ser 8, 9 o 10 : \n ");

                         scanf ( "%d",&dim);

                           /* Comprovant si la dimensio es correcta o no  */

                         if ( dim == 8 ) {

                             taulellprincipalinterrogants(taulell_vaixells_interrogants, dim);
                                                                            /* creo el taulell principal sense vaixells  */
                             inicia_taulell (dim, taulell_vaixells);               /* El passo per la funcio inicia_taulell per a que hi posi els vaixells */
                             imprimeix_taulell (taulell_vaixells, dim );           /* Imprimeixo el taulell amb els vaixells posats */

                             printf("Presiona '1' si vols continuar, si vols sortir presiona 6 : \n");
                             scanf("%d",&tecla);
                         }
                         if ( dim == 9 ) {

                             taulellprincipalinterrogants(taulell_vaixells_interrogants, dim);
                             inicia_taulell (dim, taulell_vaixells);
                             imprimeix_taulell (taulell_vaixells, dim );


                             printf("Presiona '1' si vols continuar, si vols sortir presiona 6  : \n");
                             scanf("%i",&tecla);
                         }
                         if ( dim == 10 ) {

                             taulellprincipalinterrogants(taulell_vaixells, dim);
                             inicia_taulell (dim, taulell_vaixells);
                             imprimeix_taulell (taulell_vaixells, dim );

                             printf("Presiona '1' si vols continuar, si vols sortir presiona 6  : \n");
                             scanf("%i",&tecla);

                         }

                        noficrearjoc=false;
                        segonmenu=true;

                         break;

             }
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("Has triat la opcio de carregar un joc\n");

                 printf("En el nivell 1, el que he escollit, no s'ha de poder carregar el joc");
                 printf("Presiona '1' si vols continuar o '6' si vols sortir: \n");
                 scanf("%i",&tecla);

                 nofimenu = false ;
                 segonmenu=true;
            break;

        case 5:
            printf("Has triat la opcio de veure podium\n");
                 printf("Presiona '1' si vols continuar o '6' si vols sortir: \n");
                 scanf("%i",&tecla);

                 nofimenu = true;

            break;

        case 6:
            printf("Has triat la opcio de sortir\n");
            nofimenu=false;

            break;
    }


        nofimenu=true;


    while((tecla!=6) && (segonmenu==true) && (tecla==1) && (nofimenu==true))
    {
        noficrearjoc=true;

        printf("1.Crear partida\n");
        printf("2.Carregar partida\n");
        printf("3.Jugar partida\n");
        printf("4.Emmagatzemar el joc\n");
        printf("5.Veure podium\n");
        printf("6.Sortir del joc\n");

        printf(" ************************ \n");

        printf("Escull una opció : \n");

        printf("\n"); 


        scanf("%i",&tecla2) ;


        switch (tecla2) {
            case 1:
                system("clear");
                printf("Has triat la opcio de crear un nou joc\n");
                while (noficrearjoc==true) {



                    printf("Per crear un nou joc, has d'escollir el mode de joc:\n \t 1 - Un jugador \n  \t 2 - Dos jugadors \n \t 3 - L'ordinador sol \n");

                    scanf("%d",&opciocrearjoc);

                    switch (opciocrearjoc){
                        case 1 :
                            printf( "Has triat la opcio d'un jugador\n");
                            printf(" He escollit el primer nivell, per sortir apreta el 6 : \n") ;
                            scanf("%d",&tecla);
                            break;


                        case 2 :
                            printf( "Has triat la opcio de dos jugadors\n");
                            printf(" He escollit el primer nivell, per sortir apreta el 6 : \n") ;
                            scanf("%d",&tecla);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            /* Nivell escollit = Nivell 1 */
                            system("clear");
                            printf( "Has triat la opcio de l'ordinador sol\n");

                            printf( " Introdueix la dimensió del taulell, que pot ser 8, 9 o 10 : \n ");

                            scanf ( "%d",&dim);

                            /* Comprovant si la dimensio es correcta o no  */

                            if ( dim == 8 ) {

                                taulellprincipalinterrogants(taulell_vaixells_interrogants, dim);
                                                                                        /* creo el taulell principal sense vaixells  */
                                inicia_taulell (dim, taulell_vaixells);               /* El passo per la funcio inicia_taulell per a que hi posi els vaixells */
                                imprimeix_taulell (taulell_vaixells, dim );           /* Imprimeixo el taulell amb els vaixells posats */

                                printf("Presiona 'c' si vols continuar, si vols sortir presiona 6 : \n");
                                scanf("%d",&tecla);
                            }
                            if ( dim == 9 ) {

                                taulellprincipalinterrogants(taulell_vaixells_interrogants, dim);
                                inicia_taulell (dim, taulell_vaixells);
                                imprimeix_taulell (taulell_vaixells, dim );


                                printf("Presiona '1' si vols continuar, si vols sortir presiona 6  : \n");
                                scanf("%i",&tecla);
                            }
                            if ( dim == 10 ) {

                                taulellprincipalinterrogants(taulell_vaixells, dim);
                                inicia_taulell (dim, taulell_vaixells);
                                imprimeix_taulell (taulell_vaixells, dim );

                                printf("Presiona '1' si vols continuar, si vols sortir presiona 6  : \n");
                                scanf("%i",&tecla);

                            }

                            noficrearjoc=false;
                            segonmenu=true;

                        break;                        }
                    break;

            case 2:
                    printf("Has triat la opcio de carregar un joc\n");
                    nofimenu = false ;
                    segonmenu=true;
                    printf("Presiona '1' si vols continuar : \n");
                    scanf("%i",&tecla);
                    break;
            case 3:
                /* accio jugar */

                    while ( (vaixellstrobats==false) || (col==8))
                    {

                        fila= rand() % (dim);
                        fila=fila+65;
                        col = rand() % (dim+1);
                        imprimeix_taulell(taulell_vaixells, dim);

                        res = dispara (fila, col, taulell_vaixells);
                        printf("\nResultat (%c,%d): %d", fila, col, res);

                        if (res==3)
                        {
                            cont++;

                            if (cont ==10) {
                                vaixellstrobats=true;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("En el nivell escollit no s'ha de guardar el joc\n");
                break;

            case 5:

                /*accio llegir podium del fitxer */
                break ;

            case 6 :

                printf("Has triat sortir del joc\n");
                nofimenu=false;
                break;



                }
        }

    }

}


 }
 return (0);

   }
```

Comment: You know there are functions? And that you can write your code in such way that others can read it?

Comment: But the problem isn't that the functions are wrong, my problem is that the chart given by the functions in the beginning doesn't remain the same all the program. If i print the table next to the function that makes it, the chart is perfect, but if i print the chart outside that Switch, the chart goes crazy...

Comment: It's a messy large program, fix it in terms for formatting and style, use more functions to isolate the code (*every function has to do just one thing, including `main()`*). Don't declare more than one variable per line, that should help a lot in finding the issue. Also, use a debugger and step through the code.